# How to define string based on host os in bazel rule definition?

Tags: bazel

I have the following rule definition:

```
helm_action = rule(
    attrs = {
        …
        "cluster_aliases": attr.string_dict(
            doc = "key value pair matching for creating a cluster alias where the name used to evoke a cluster alias is different than the actual cluster's name",
            default = DEFAULT_CLUSTER_ALIASES,
        ),
        …
    },
    …
)
```

I'd like for `DEFAULT_CLUSTER_ALIASES` value to be based on the host os but

```
DEFAULT_CLUSTER_ALIASES = {
    "local": select({
        "@platforms//os:osx": "docker-desktop",
        "@platforms//os:linux": "minikube",
    })
}
```

errors with:

```
Error in string_dict: expected value of type 'string' for dict value element, but got select({"@platforms//os:osx": "docker-desktop", "@platforms//os:linux": "minikube"}) (select)
```

How do I go about defining `DEFAULT_CLUSTER_ALIASES` based on the host os?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a rule or macro, it is evaluated during the loading phase, before command-line flags are evaluated. Bazel needs to know the default value in your build rule `helm_action` during the loading phase but can't because it hasn't parsed the command line and analysed the build graph.

The command line is parsed and select statements are evaluated during the analysis phase. As a broad rule, if your select statement isn't in a BUILD.bazel then it's not going to work. So the easiest way to achieve what you are after is to create a macro that uses your rule injecting the default. e.g.

```py
# helm_action.bzl
# Add an '_' prefix to your rule to make the rule private.
_helm_action = rule(
    attrs = {
        …
        "cluster_aliases": attr.string_dict(
            doc = "key value pair matching for creating a cluster alias where the name used to evoke a cluster alias is different than the actual cluster's name",
        # Remove default attribute.
        ),
        …
    },
    …
)

# Wrap your rule in a publicly exported macro.
def helm_action(**kwargs):
    _helm_action(
        name = kwargs["name"],
        # Instantiate your rule with a select.
        cluster_aliases = DEFAULT_CLUSTER_ALIASES,
        **kwargs,
    )
```

It's important to note the difference between a macro and a rule. A macro is a way of generating a set of targets using other build rules, and actually expands out roughly equivalent to it's contents when used in a BUILD file. You can check this by querying a target with the `--output build` flag. e.g.

```py
load(":helm_action.bzl", "helm_action")

helm_action(
    name = "foo",
    # ...
)
```

You can query the output using the command;

`bazel query //:foo --output build`

This will demonstrate that the select statement is being copied into the BUILD file.

A good example of this approach is in the [rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/2a8565c52be9a98ecc1a2057e23ade8315860153/go/image.bzl) repository.

**EDIT**: The question was clarified, so I've got an updated answer below but will keep the above answer in case it is useful to others.

A simple way of achieving what you are after is to use Bazels [toolchain api](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/toolchains.html). This is a very flexible API and is what most language rulesets use in Bazel. e.g.

Create a build file with your toolchains;

```py
# //helm:BUILD.bazel
load(":helm_toolchains.bzl", "helm_toolchain")
toolchain_type(name = "toolchain_type")

helm_toolchain(
   name = "osx",
   cluster_aliases = {
     "local": "docker-desktop",
   },
)

toolchain(
    name = "osx_toolchain",
    toolchain = ":osx",
    toolchain_type = ":toolchain_type",
    exec_compatible_with = ["@platforms//os:macos"],
    # Optionally use to restrict target platforms too.
    # target_compatible_with = []
)

helm_toolchain(
   name = "linux",
   cluster_aliases = {
     "local": "minikube",
   },
)

toolchain(
    name = "linux_toolchain",
    toolchain = ":linux",
    toolchain_type = ":toolchain_type",
    exec_compatible_with = ["@platforms//os:linux"],
)
```

Register your toolchains so that Bazel knows what to look for;

```py
# //:WORKSPACE
# the rest of your workspace...
register_toolchains("//helm:all")

# You may need to register your execution platforms too...
# register_execution_platforms("//your_platforms/...")
```

Implement the toolchain backend;

```py
# //helm:helm_toolchains.bzl
HelmToolchainInfo = provider(fields = ["cluster_aliases"])

def _helm_toolchain_impl(ctx):
    toolchain_info = platform_common.ToolchainInfo(
        helm_toolchain_info = HelmToolchainInfo(
            cluster_aliases = ctx.attr.cluster_aliases,
        ),
    )
    return [toolchain_info]

helm_toolchain = rule(
    implementation = _helm_toolchain_impl,
    attrs = {
        "cluster_aliases": attr.string_dict(),
    },
)
```

Update `helm_action` to use toolchains. e.g.

```py
def _helm_action_impl(ctx):
    cluster_aliases = ctx.toolchains["@your_repo//helm:toolchain_type"].helm_toolchain_info.cluster_aliases
    #...

helm_action = rule(
    _helm_action_impl,
    attrs = {
        #…
    },
    toolchains = ["@your_repo//helm:toolchain_type"]
)
```

Comment: After voting this up, it turns out it doesn't do what I want which is to `select` based on the _host_ os, not the target os.

Comment: Got an updated answer that should do what you are after, there's a fair bit of boilerplate there but it should be extensible for almost all of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2045, selecting based on host os is not possible.

Comment: It is actually possible, but only on label typed attributes not string_dict as in your question. Take a look at the 'cfg' field in the [attr docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/attr.html#label). By setting this to `exec` any select will be configured for the execution environment rather than the target environment.

Comment: Can you provide a working example as an answer?